# Kong API Gateway SSL/TLS Certificates

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, kong, konga

I got a problem with SSL/TLS Termination on Kong API Gateway. HTTPS Requests using curl and Insomnia got response that **SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate**.
Certificate is valid and issued by well known issuer, so CA certificate is already in the clients known CA list.
In Browser HTTPS requests works fine.

I'm using **Kong version 2.7.1**

**docker-compose.yaml** configured in next way:

```
  kong:
    image: kong:2.7.1
    container_name: kong-api-gw
    restart: always
    networks:
      kong-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.1.11
    volumes:
      - kong-volume:/etc/kong
      - kong-volume-conf:/usr/local/kong
    environment:
      KONG_DATABASE: postgres
      KONG_PG_HOST: kong-database
      KONG_PG_DATABASE: kong
      KONG_PG_USER: ${KONG_PG_USER}
      KONG_PG_PASSWORD: ${KONG_PG_PASSWORD}
      KONG_PROXY_LISTEN: 0.0.0.0:8000, 0.0.0.0:8443 ssl
      KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN: 0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl
      KONG_SSL: "on"
      KONG_SSL_CERT: /etc/kong/ssl/kong.crt
      KONG_SSL_CERT_KEY: /etc/kong/ssl/kong.key
      KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG: /dev/stdout
      KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG:  /dev/stdout
    depends_on:
      - kong-database
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "kong", "health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "8001:8001"
      - "8443:8443"
      - "8444:8444"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "2"
          memory: "4000M"
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
          max-file: "3"
          max-size: "10M"
```

Certificate was added using Admin API and Konga UI, i tried pem and crt, both of them.

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8001/certificates -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' -F cert=@./kong.pem -F key=@./kong.key -F snis[]=example.com
```

Inside docker container i put mycert.crt and mycert.key to /etc/kong/ssl/, but nothing helped and there are no errors in logs.

Response from GET Request to https://example.com:8444/certificates (when disable SSL Validation in Insomnia)

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "key_alt": null,
            "created_at": 1650871124,
            "cert_alt": null,
            "key": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\cert-key-example\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----",
            "id": "7ebdca61-4598-4e17-bdf8-2239c41ce09b",
            "tags": null,
            "snis": [
                "example.com"
            ],
            "cert": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\cert-example\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
        }
    ],
    "next": null
}
```

Curl example

```
curl -i -v https://example.com:8443/api
*   Trying ip:8443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example.com (ip) port 8443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Comment: Can you download the certicate `echo -n | openssl s_client -connect $HOST:$PORTNUMBER -servername $SERVERNAME | openssl x509 > /tmp/certificate.crt` Then `openssl x509 -text -noout -in certificate.crt`

Comment: Yes, i can download it, one more thing that worried me is next error during executing command 
`openssl verify kong.crt`
output - `kong.crt: CN = myexample.com
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate`
still trying to understand why certificate works perfectly while using it in httpd.conf, but facing problems during openssl verification.

Comment: more strange that i can verify it in docker, but can't do this on host
`openssl verify -CAfile kong.ca.crt kong.crt`
output - `kong.crt: OK`

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug, i figured it out, Kong needs ca-bundle certificate not just crt. So you need to combine root and intermediate certificates. Together with your server certificate (issued specifically for your domain), these files complete the SSL chain of trust. At the end i just used Kong Admin API to upload certificate using Konga Web UI or POST request like:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://example.com:8001/certificates \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F cert=@./kong.ca-bundle \
  -F key=@./kong.key \
  -F snis[]=example.com
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried to upload ca-bundle and .key file, but getting below issue                                      {
    "code": 2,
    "fields": {
        "@entity": [
            "certificate does not match key"
        ]
    },
    "name": "schema violation",
    "message": "schema violation (certificate does not match key)"
} . But I am able to upload crt file with the same key @user16241090

Answer (score 0):

i'am try with .ca-bundle but not work, error invalid key, then i try with .crt and .key file with private key it is works

```
  curl -X POST \
  http://example.com:8001/certificates \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F cert=@./kong.crt \
  -F key=@./kong.key \
  -F snis[]=example.com
```